What do the axes represent on this Riemann surface of the complex logarithm?
My question seems to a special case of the answer to this question: What does the Color and height of a Riemann surface represent, but that post seems to make use of more advanced techniques than I currently have available to me. I am trying to understand this image from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface:

This is apparently a plot of the riemann surface of $\operatorname{Log}(z)$. Certainly the x/y axes on this plot represent the real/imaginary axes of the complex plane. I had believed that colour represented phase of the output, and the height represented magnitude of output, but this cannot be true as there is a negative height marker. What does the height represent?

If you go to the source page for this image on Wikimedia Commons, it includes a one-sentence summary: "Riemann surface of Log[z], projection from 4dim C x C to 3dim C x Im(C), color is argument." But the imaginary part of Log[z] is the argument of z, so it seems like both color and height represent the same information.
